# Camera zooming effect

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, camera, scaling, zooming

I'm looking for a camera zooming effect like the one used in Tiny Wings, where the camera zooms out based on the characters height.

I want the character to start zooming after it reaches a set height and I want the zooming to be non-linear so that the character gradually gets closer to the camera bounds as it goes higher up the screen.

I'm currently using the following code to scale linearly

```
 camera.scale = MIN(1, SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.7 / player_position_y);
```

This results in the player always being 30% away from the top of the screen. I'm trying to find an elegant solution that will result in the player going between 30% from the edge of the screen to 10% from the edge of the screen depending on how high in the game world the character goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion I'm posting the solution I came up with.

```
        float scalar = 4; // Had to tweak this number to get the difference in scales to feel right
        float distance = player_position_y - SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.7;

        float percentage = distance/(SCREEN_HEIGHT*2 - SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.7)

        percentage = 1 - (percentage/scalar);

        self.scale = MIN(1, SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.70 / (player_position_y * percentage));
```

Basically I get the distance between where the character starts scaling and the max height the character can reach as a percentage of the max height.

I invert that number and multiply it by a scaler. I multiply this percentage value by the player height used in the scale calculation. This results in the scale calculation using a position for the character that moves lower than the character as the character gains height.